# Displaying a text on the last page of crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

This might be a very naive question but i am not able to get to it.

I have a simple text object that i wish to display only on the last page of the report after all my details section and group footer sections are displayed.

I have tried applying Suppress property on page footer to work, but it does not happen. Then i tried suppressing the text object but that did not work as well.

This is what i pushed into formula field:

if PageNumber = TotalPageCount then
    false
else
    true

Am i missing something.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your text object in the Report Footer section.

Answer (score 0):

you will required to use Report Footer. please follow a link. if this is the answer to your question mark the answer.

Link:.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crconreportfooter.htm

Comment: I cant use that because Report Footer will print it just before the end of page. However, i wish to print the Text Object just after the end of details section.


For Ex:
my details section takes half of my page, then i want the text object to be next after the details section and not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: report footer will print after your detail, not at the bottom of page.
Report  Footer/ Page Footer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a section below the last group and place your text field there so that when ever everything is displayed you will get the required text

```
E.g:
If you have Group1 and Group2 then create a section in group footer of Group1 using "Insert Section below and place the Text field there.
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved...!!! The problem was that in the Format Text dialog box, after writing the formula i had checked the Suppress Check Box because of which the Text Object was Suppressed all the time. Thanks for all your help...!!